# Dynamically set inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have class `A` that is supposed to inherit class `B` whose name is not yet known at the time of `A` being written. Is it possible to declare `A` not inheriting anything, and add `B` as the base class during `A`'s instantiation? Example:

First file

```
class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__name = "Class B"

  def name(self):
    return self.__name
```

Second file

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__name = "Class A"

# At some point here, the appropriate module name and location is discovered
import sys
sys.path.append(CustomModulePath)
B = __import__(CustomModuleName)

magic(A, B) # TODO What should magic() do?

a = A()
print a.name() # This will now print "Class A", since name() is defined in B.
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: In this application I need to manipulate classes based on the application-specific metadata, not by regular class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can accomplish this with metaclasses. It's not the easiest topic to wrap your head around but it'll do the job. There's a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) question about them that looks like it has some good information and I also found an [IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html) that might help as well. Somewhere in the official Python documentation, there's a section about them but I can't recall exactly where offhand.

Comment: the SO question particularly has an example on how to mess with inheritance, so look there for sure

Comment: Looks like metaclasses are exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!